# What does output indicate when larger address is subtracted from smaller address in C/C++ programming?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc, memory

Given a snippet of code as:

```c
int a[5];
printf("%u\n",&a[3]-&a[0]);
printf("%u",&a[0]-&a[3]);
```

now the output of first line in subtraction of addresses is as per formula ( (addg - adds)/size of data type ) where, addg is greater than adds.
The output for above snippet in gcc is:

```
3
4294967293
```

The first line output (i.e. is 3) is obvious but what is the meaning of second output or what happens when larger address is subtracted from smaller one (i.e. adds - addg)?

Comment: As you see, it wraps. It would be "negative" but since addresses are unsigned you see it as a large positive number.

Comment: more Hint: what's the most negative number a unsigned int can represent ;)

Comment: Meaningless implementation defined behaviour. You appear to have hit unsigned overflow, but I wouldn't want to rely on that.

Comment: The result of pointer difference have the type `ptrdiff_t`. To use [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to print such a type you need to use the `t` prefix, as in `%td` or `%tu`. Mismatching format-specifier and argument-type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have *undefined behaviour*. Not because of the pointer arithmetic but because you are printing *signed* integers using the `%u` format specifier.  Change to the `%td` format (the `t` to specify a 'pointer difference' type) and you will see more meaningful results:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5];
    printf("%td\n", &a[3] - &a[0]); // Shows "3"
    printf("%td", &a[0] - &a[3]);   // Shows "-3"
    return 0;
}
```

From this [C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (Section **6.5.6** Paragraph #9) (bolding mine):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
> same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
> the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
> elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its
> type (a ***signed integer type***) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>`
> header ...